# Changing values of elements in a vector using a function

Tags: c++, vector

I just started learning C++ today so I'm not familiar with whether I'm referencing the original vector or a copy. I'm trying to double the values of all the elements in my vector (go from 1, 2, 3 to 2, 4, 6) but the vector always prints the original values. Any tips are appreciated!

```
void doubleVector(vector<int> vec) {
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
        vec[i] = vec[i] * 2;
    }
}

int main() {
    vector<int> vect{ 1, 2, 3 };
    doubleVector(vect);
    for (int x : vect) {
        std::cout << x << ' ';
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a copy. `void doubleVector(vector<int> & vec)` would be a pass by reference.

Comment: Unrelated: you could write `for (int & val:vec) { val *= 2; }`. This lets the compiler figure out all of the iteration logic for you just like the loop in `main`. Note that `val` is a also reference to prevent operating on a copy.

Comment: Unfortunately, though there are probably over a thousand duplicates of this exact problem, the vernacular and titles used to describe the posts makes them near-unhittable when searching for key terms. The short order is, you're passing your vector by value, so only the local vector `vec` is actually changed. It is the same as a non-complex object: `(int x)` and then `x = x+1;` for example; would suffer the same fate. Changing to a reference, `vector<int> &vec` , will deliver the behavior you seek.

Comment: @OP It doesn't matter if it's a simple `int` or a `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>`.  Variables in C++ are passed by value (a copy is created), unless you specifically state to pass by reference.  This is the big difference between languages like Python or Java, and C++.

Comment: The fun one is `void func(type * pointer)` what `pointer` points at is passed by a type of reference and can be modified inside `func` with lasting effects but `pointer` itself is passed by value and a copy. If you need to change where `pointer` points in `func`, you need to pass `pointer` by reference: `void func(type * & pointer)`

Comment: Great to see you starting your learning of C++ with `vector` and not `new` and `delete`-ing arrays. Sounds like you're working from some decent learning materials.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change an object, you need to pass it by pointer of by reference.

Here, you pass `vector<int> vec` to the function `doubleVector` which will copy your vector instead of passing it.

Remplace that by `void doubleVector(vector<int>& vec)` and it will work fine.